# Dúvida Session Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Eu preciso passar o id de um usuário por uma sessão, pois está acontecendo de misturar os usuários, pois estava sendo gravada em uma variável, tem alguma forma, de continuar passando pela variável, sem ter que alterar em todo o projeto, pois em todo projeto ele já esta sendo pego pela variável da classe.
No caso alguma forma de passar a sessão pra variável somente ?
Tentei passando direto do default, mas como está passando pra variável, sem nenhuma verificação, ainda está misturando.

Comment: _tem alguma forma de continuar passando pela variável sem ter que alterar em todo o projeto_: Bem vinda aos efeitos colaterais de desenvolvimento não planejado! Qualquer gambiarra para isso vai só alimentar o mostro que tu tá criando. Acho que dar uns dois passos para trás, conceber melhor a sua ideia e organizar o projeto todo vai ser um investimento bem melhor

Comment: Realmente Diego,  peguei o projeto já em andamento, mas infelizmente se não tiver outra alternativa terei q alterar em todo o projeto. Qual forma você me aconselha, para algo seguro mesmo que tenha que alterar em todo o projeto ?

Comment: Costumo ver muito comumente autenticação via forms. [Neste tutorial do Marcoratti ele mostra um passo-a-passo para esse tipo de autenticação](http://www.macoratti.net/10/08/aspn_aut1.htm) que é bem trivial. Veja se serve para você.

Comment: Na verdade a autenticação já é feita, eu só preciso de uma forma segura, se passar o id do usuário que está autenticando, para salvar por exemplo o ID correto no log, ou para verificar se o usuário tem acesso a tal pagina. Conforme expliquei na pergunta, elas se misturam por variável de classe, no caso seria colocar a sessão em cada um mesmo? É a melhor forma?

Comment: Então... Não existe "bala de prata". O seu cenário é que vai dizer o que é melhor. Especificamente, vocÊ pode guardar os dados do usuário autenticado na sessão ou controlar via cookies. Guardar na sessão pode ser interessante para vocÊ porque pode não mudar tanto o tratamento que você já tem com a sua variável. [Dá um google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=controle+de+sess%C3%A3o+de+usu%C3%A1rio+asp+net&oq=controle+de+sess%C3%A3o+de+usu%C3%A1rio+asp+net&aqs=chrome..69i57.5315j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza pesquisando, encontrei este link na internet https://webmaicon.wordpress.com/2009/01/15/criando-uma-simples-classe-session-em-aspnet-c/ será que pode ocorrer de misturar os usuários desta forma?

Comment: Sim, isso deve funcionar sem problemas para você. Parece bem simples de fazer. Boa sorte =)